# Multiple download with Background Downloader in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i can download a file into SD CARD by this code>

```
    DownloadOperation downloadOperation;
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;

    BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
    async private void ButtonDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (sdCard != null)
        {
            StorageFile file = await sdCard.CreateFileAsync("Downloads\\d460809d2cef1.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(new Uri("http://dowmain.com/uploads/d460809d2cef1.pdf"), file);
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Progress<DownloadOperation> progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(progressChanged);
            cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            try
            {
                await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progress);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download canceled.";
                downloadOperation.ResultFile.DeleteAsync();
                downloadOperation = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void progressChanged(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
    {
        int progress = (int)(100 * ((double)downloadOperation.Progress.BytesReceived / (double)downloadOperation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive));
        TextBlockProgress.Text = String.Format("{0} of {1} kb. downloaded - %{2} complete.", downloadOperation.Progress.BytesReceived / 1024, downloadOperation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024, progress);
        ProgressBarDownload.Value = progress;
        switch (downloadOperation.Progress.Status)
        {
            case BackgroundTransferStatus.Running:
                {
                    TextBlockStatus.Text = "Downloading...";
                    ButtonPauseResume.Content = "Pause";
                    break;
                }
            case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedByApplication:
                {
                    TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download paused.";
                    ButtonPauseResume.Content = "Resume";
                    break;
                }
            case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedCostedNetwork:
                {
                    TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download paused because of metered connection.";
                    ButtonPauseResume.Content = "Resume";
                    break;
                }
            case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedNoNetwork:
                {
                    TextBlockStatus.Text = "No network detected. Please check your internet connection.";
                    break;
                }
            case BackgroundTransferStatus.Error:
                {
                    TextBlockStatus.Text = "An error occured while downloading.";
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (progress >= 100)
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download complete.";
            downloadOperation = null;
        }
    }
```

I have 2 question:

1. I want to download multiple files and show the process, but i don't know how should I do that. can you give me a solution or source code ?
2. I can access to SD Card for download, but how can i download a file into my Phone memory?

Comment: Take a look at `BackgroundTransferGroup` if you want to download multiple files.  http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/09/01/Whats-New-in-Windows-81-Background-Tasks.aspx?Page=1.  As for the SD card, you'll just need to replace `sdCard` with `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Your file downloading code is working fine. But continuously status update is not happening here,

for your 2nd question you can download your pdf file into Windows Phone Storage with this.

```
  StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

  var file= await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("fileName", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

The Other things will remain the same. 
Hope this will work,